# How to delete plugin in vim?

Tags: vim

I wrote vim script and copied into ~/.vim/plugin/ directory.
But that script had syntax error so it fail to load in gvim.

After fixing I tried again but it seen it not reading updated file.
Even I tried deleting "~/.vim" directory but still same behavior.

Please some one help me to know how to delete vim plugin ?

Thanks,
~Rohit

Comment: Try to open vim with `vim --noplugin file` ?

Comment: What was the error faced?

Answer (score 2):

Plugins are just like text files. They come into effect only when vim is running. Unlike executables files, vim plugins don't have any uninstallion method. You just delete the plugins, they are removed permanently. If you don't want to delete them, you can move them to other folders other than HOME directory or rename them. I rename `.vim` to `.VIM` when my plugin throws error.